# Greasemonkey script stop working when require this js

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

My script stop working when I use @require with this js library.
It works in Tampermonkey.

This is the minimal code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @version      1
// @namespace    test

// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.2.3/masonry.pkgd.min.js

// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// @match        *

// ==/UserScript==

alert('999');
```

ps: why did someone vote down this question? what's wrong?

Comment: I can't get the masonry library to load in tampermonkey without an error. You may need to manually edit the masonry library to work properly. Also, you may want to change match to include

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why but I've found a solution: insert a script tag into the head tag.